# How to Build AAR and Sample Application

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aar

I'm running into a collection of gradle problems in setting up a multi-module project.  I'm trying to produce an AAR that contains an SDK for our customers use.  I'm also trying to produce a sample application that uses that AAR both as a development platform internally and as an example for our customers of how to use the platform.

settings.gradle:

```
include :sdk
include :SampleApplication
```

build.gradle:

```
...
// copy the AAR produced by the SDK into the SampleApplication
task import_aar(type: Copy) {
  dependsOn ":sdk:build"
  from(new File(project(':sdk').getBuildDir(), 'outputs/aar')) {
    include '*-release.aar'
    rename '(.*)-release.aar', '$1-v1.0.0.aar'
  }
  into new File(project(':SampleApplication').projectDir, 'aars')
}
...
```

SampleApplication/build.gradle:

```
...
repositories {
    ...
    flatDir {
        dirs 'aars'
    }
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    // This causes gradle to fail if the AAR hasn't been copied yet
    compile 'com.moxiesoft.netagent:moxieMobileSDK:+@aar'                                                                                            
    compile project(':moxieMobileSDK')
    ...
}
```

So the biggest problem that I'm having right now is getting the `import_aar` task to run before the `compileDebug/ReleaseSources` tasks.  I've tried adding explicit dependencies to the compile tasks, but I'm apparently not finding the right way to do it.

I've tried putting this in SampleApplication/settings.gradle:

```
tasks['compileReleaseSources'].dependsOn(':import_aar')
```

but gradle fails because there's no `compileReleaseSources` task, even though gradle :SampleApplication:tasks shows one.

I also tried putting similar stuff in settings.gradle, but it also failed with an error that the task compileReleaseSources didn't exist.

I did have limited success by putting this in my SampleApplication/settings.gradle:

```
tasks['build'].dependsOn(':import_aar')
```

But that only has the correct affect if I use "gradle build", which doesn't happen if I'm debugging or running from Android Studio.

I was finally able to get this to work by putting the dependsOn on the preBuild task, but I'm still not particularly happy with the solution, because:

1. It requires me to have the aar in place before gradle runs, which
   means I wind up putting the .aar into git, which isn't a
   particularly good idea.
2. I'd rather not have the AAR generation leaking into the
   SampleApplication/build.gradle file, since that's intended for
   customer usage.

Is there a better way of handling the problem in general?

Comment: I don't know about "better", but here's what I do for my CWAC libraries, which have a similar library-and-demo setup. I have `debug` demo app builds just point to the library module (e.g., `debugCompile project(':lib')`). I publish my AAR to my Maven repo using the `maven` plugin (and in my case an additional script, since my repo is on Amazon S3). My demo app then uses `releaseCompile` to pull in the artifact from the repo, to confirm that I can build against the AAR. My approach could use some polish, but it's getting the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problem adding a dependency to compileReleaseSources task and [described here](http://howto-and-stuff.blogspot.com/2017/10/adding-dependency-to.html) a solution that worked for me.  In short, the dependency need to be added in tasks.whenTaskAdded closure.